# Firebase Authentication is not working after deploy. Flutter Web App shows blank white screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I deployed my Flutter Web App with Firebase Auth and Firebase Firestore with `flutter build web` and `firebase deploy`.

The Problem is after I deployed the web app  I only see a blank white screen.

Web App is hosted with Firebase.

Does anyone have experience with this problem?

Part of my pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  blur: ^3.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  email_validator: ^2.1.17
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
  firebase_auth_web: ^5.3.0
  firebase_core: ^2.9.0
  fl_chart: ^0.61.0
  fl_heatmap: ^0.2.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_heatmap_calendar: ^1.0.5
  flutter_styled_toast: ^2.1.3
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.5
  google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.4.0+7
  intl: 0.17.0
  pie_chart: ^5.3.2
  pointer_interceptor: ^0.9.3+4
  provider: ^6.0.5
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

My void main():

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  const FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    projectId: "projectId",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
    appId: "appId",
  );
  await Firebase.initializeApp(name: "name", options: firebaseOptions);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

MyApp Widget:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => TimeProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
        key: _key,
        scaffoldMessengerKey: Utils.messengerKey,
        home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const LoadingAuthScreen();
            } else {
              return const AuthPage();
            }
          },
        ), //const DrawerHome(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Script-Tag:

```
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-auth.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "apiKey",
      authDomain: "authDomain",
      databaseURL: "databaseURL",
      projectId: "projectId",
      storageBucket: "storageBucket",
      messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
      appId: "appId",
      measurementId: "measurementId"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue in the past and What I have to do to fix it:

- run `flutter clean`
- remove your old configuration in the web
- try the new way to integrate Firebase in Flutter using `flutterfire_cli`

Go through the following documentation once

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web